# In Ubercart auction final bid amount adds sell price instead of highest bid amount in the cart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

In uber-cart after auction has been won, the buyer will get add-to-cart button to add and buy the product. After clicking on add-to-cart button, it adds sell price value in the cart page instead of highest bid amount.

**How to make it add highest bid amount in cart page instead of sell-price.**

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements uc_cart_alter.
 */
function mymodule_uc_cart_alter(&$items ) {

  foreach ($items as $index => $item) {

   //you can add condition for your bid product

    $items[$index]->price = 100;
  }
}
```

For reference:

http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_uc_cart_alter